# Smooth animation with timer and loop in iOS app

Tags: swift, animation, timer, grand-central-dispatch

I have ViewController with stars rating that looks like this (except that there are 10 stars)

[image]

When user opens ViewController for some object that have no rating I want to point user's attention to this stars with very simple way: animate stars highlighting (you could see such behaviour on some ads in real world when each letter is highlighted one after another).

1. One star highlighted
2. Two stars highlighted
3. Three stars highlighted
4. ......
5. Turn off all of them

So this is the way how I am doing it

```
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
        completion()
    }
} 

func ratingStarsAnimation() {
    for i in 1...11 {
        var timer : Double = 0.6 + Double(i)*0.12
        delayWithSeconds(timer) {
            ratingStars.rating = (i < 10) ? Double(i) : 0
        }
    }
}
```

What is going on here? I have function called delayWithSeconds that delays action and I use this function to delay each star highlighting. And 0.6 is initial delay before animation begins. After all stars are highlighted - last step is to turn off highlighting of all stars.
This code works but I can't say that it is smooth.

**My questions are:**

1. How can I change 0.6 + Double(i)*0.12 to get smooth animation feel?
2. I think that my solution with delays is not good - how can I solve smooth stars highlighting task better?

Comment: Can you show that animation which you have achieved so far and the one which you want to.

Comment: How can I show it?

Comment: Share video by dropBox.

Comment: I will make whichever type of animation you want

Comment: Now I can only show you example of rhythm close to desired animation https://giphy.com/gifs/mac-cosmetics-ledisko-CMf07Y5o9yLDi - if you look on big letters (L & R) - you can see that they become highlighted  with non-linear way and from slow to fast

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the CADisplaylink class. Its a specialized timer that is linked to the refresh rate of the screen, on iOS this is 60fps.
It's the backbone of many 3rd party animation libraries.

Usage example:

```
var displayLink: CADisplayLink?
let start: Double = 0
let end: Double = 10
let duration: CFTimeInterval = 5 // seconds
var startTime: CFTimeInterval = 0

let ratingStars = RatingView()

func create() {
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(tick))
    displayLink?.add(to: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
}

func tick() {
    guard let link = displayLink else {
        cleanup()
        return
    }

    if startTime == 0 { // first tick
        startTime = link.timestamp
        return
    }

    let maxTime = startTime + duration
    let currentTime = link.timestamp

    guard currentTime < maxTime else {
        finish()
        return
    }

    // Add math here to ease the animation

    let progress = (currentTime - startTime) / duration
    let progressInterval = (end - start) * Double(progress)

    // get value =~ 0...10
    let normalizedProgress = start + progressInterval


    ratingStars.rating = normalizedProgress
}

func finish() {
    ratingStars.rating = 0
    cleanup()
}

func cleanup() {
    displayLink?.remove(from: .main, forMode: .defaultRunLoopMode)
    displayLink = nil
    startTime = 0
}
```

As a start this will allow your animation to be smoother. You will still need to add some trigonometry if you want to add easing but that shouldn't be too difficult.

- CADisplaylink:
  https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cadisplaylink
- Easing curves: http://gizma.com/easing/